# Missing data constructor HostAny in Haskell

Tags: haskell, conduit, network-conduit

I am experimenting with Conduit Network and I cannot compile this code because it is cannot find the data constructor: HostAny

conduit-extra is installed so I am very puzzled why it cannot find it?

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Data.Conduit
import Data.Conduit.Network


serverApp :: AppData -> IO ()
serverApp d = do appSource d $$ appSink d

main :: IO()
main = runTCPServer (serverSettings 8900 HostAny) serverApp
```

Here's the GHC error:

pez@devbox:~/dev$ runhaskell server.hs

```
server.hs:10:42: Not in scope: data constructor `HostAny'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-extra-1.1.0.3/docs/Data-Conduit-Network.html#t%3aHostPreference) for `conduit-extras`, you'll see

> data HostPreference
>
> Which host to bind.
>
> Note: The IsString instance recognizes the following special values:
>
> ```
> * means HostAny
> *4 means HostIPv4
> !4 means HostIPv4Only
> *6 means HostIPv6
> !6 means HostIPv6Only
> ```

Which tells me that you should be using the extension `OverloadedStrings` and then you can just write your code as

```
main = runTCPServer (serverSettings 8900 "*") serverApp
```

Although I have to say that is a strange API this library has chosen.  I personally would much rather have the ability to use `IsString` or an explicit constructor in cases where I don't want to use `OverloadedStrings` for whatever reason.